# Implementation of boolean function using multiplexer

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, boolean-algebra

## Is the following question correct?

## Consider the Boolean expression F(A,B,C) = ABC+ AB+ AC.

Implement this logic expression using one 4x1 multiplexer. Do not use C as an input to the selectors of the multiplexer.

[image]

Also,Can someone give me a hint or push me in the right direction,as i was thinking of using the above method? Thanks in advance

Comment: It took me a while to realize that the picture illustrates a method, not the same problem described in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I wouldn't use that method. Instead,

- Simplify the given function
- Since you can't connect C, connect A and B to the select inputs of the multiplexer.
- Figure out what needs to be connected to each of the four multiplexer data inputs. The choices are 0, 1 or C.